# How can I make this more Readable and more clearer

Tags: python

I just got into programming again used to code but lost touch with it. Any feedback would be appreciated on this code and tips on how to get alot more better at it. I want to land a internship as a self taught programmer.

list = [ "python", "jumble", "easy", "difficult", "answer",  "xylophone"]
display = []

```
stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']
characters_left_to_guess=  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
#step 1 get a random word
import random
random_word = random.choice(list)
word_length=len(random_word)
print(random_word)
end_of_game = False
lives = 6
#step 2 generate as many blanks = letters in word
for letters in random_word:
  display += "_"
while not end_of_game:
  #step 3 ask the user to guess a letter and make sure the same letter cannot be asked twice
  guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
  while guess not in characters_left_to_guess:
    guess = input(f"You have already guessed {guess}. Guess another letter please:")
  characters_left_to_guess.remove(guess)
    

  for position in range(word_length):
    letter = random_word[position]
    if letter == guess:
      display[position] = letter
  if guess not in random_word:
    lives -= 1
    print(f"You have {lives} guesses left.")
    if lives == 0:
      end_of_game = True
      print("You lose try again")
  if "_" not in display:
    end_of_game = True
    print("You win")
  
  print(display)
  print(stages[lives])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is probably more suitable for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0):

here --->   `random_word = random.choice(list)`
you should not call it a "list" otherwise the computer will give an error
Also, you have not defined "display " in this line here > display += "*"
and you should also put brackets around the "*"
and in this line `print(f"You have {lives} guesses left.")` you should change it to `print(f"You have",{lives},"guesses left")` and you also need to difine "lives"

Comment: Weird on my code. I defined display as an empty list, so for each letter in the word it would append a empty blank. I also defined lives as well in the code I had, I don't understand why it didnt copy and paste there. But on the other points thanks for the help.

Comment: anything else??

Comment: you need help with?

Comment: And also stack overflow is for asking questions about how you can fix your code not how you can improve it, if improving is needed head over to code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay thank you for the help.